# store excel data in sql server table using FileUpload functionality

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, file-upload

I need to give user a functionality of file upload where user can browse for a file and upload it to server. Data stored in the file will be extracted and inserted into a table. File has 4 columns and no of rows can change every time.

Backend code:

```
    Protected Sub btnUploadFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUploadFile.Click

        Dim _FileUpload As New FileUpload

        If (_FileUpload.HasFile) Then
            If Not IsDBNull(_FileUpload.PostedFile) And _FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
                _FileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\" + _FileUpload.FileName)
                Dim oSqlBulk As SqlBulkCopy
                Dim myExcelConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath(".") & "\" & _FileUpload.FileName() & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
                Try
                    myExcelConn.Open()
                    Dim objOleDB As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Transaction Ref],[Acquisition Nominal],[Acquisition Date],[Acquisition Price] FROM [Sheet1$]", myExcelConn)
                    Dim objBulkReader As OleDbDataReader
                    objBulkReader = objOleDB.ExecuteReader

                    Dim sCon As String = "Data Source=DNA;Persist Security Info=False;" &
                        "Integrated Security=SSPI;" &
                        "Initial Catalog=DNA_Classified;User Id=sa;Password=;" &
                        "Connect Timeout=30;"

                    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(sCon)
                        con.Open()
                        oSqlBulk = New SqlBulkCopy(con)
                        oSqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "IDCOPES..T_CDI_ACQUISITION"
                        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Transaction Ref", "RefNo")
                        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Acquisition Nominal", "AcqNominalAmt")
                        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Acquisition Date", "AcqDate")
                        oSqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Acquisition Price", "Price")
                        oSqlBulk.WriteToServer(objBulkReader)
                    End Using

                Catch ex As Exception

                Finally
                    oSqlBulk.Close() : oSqlBulk = Nothing
                    myExcelConn.Close() : myExcelConn = Nothing
                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Frontend:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="panelFileUpload" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblFileUpload" runat="server" Text="File Upload:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:FileUpload CssClass = "FileUpload" ID="fuFileUpload" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFile" runat="server" CssClass="inputButton" OnClientClick="fnStartInterval()" Text="Upload" ValidationGroup="A" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuFileUpload" Font-Italic="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="A">*Please choose a file to upload! </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Since table has more columns than excel file, I have used column mappings. IDCOPES is the database and T_CDI_ACQUISITION is the table. But when I run this, there is no error in file uploading but the data is not inserted in the table. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
st = "select " + Str + " from [Sheet1$]"
  //str is given below


                MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(st, MyConnection)




            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
            dt = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dt)
```

We are saving str as string actually testtable contains F50 columns where you can map fields in dt from excel.

str string  will be something like this  [Transaction Ref],[Acquisition Nominal],[Acquisition Date],[Acquisition Price] 
'' as F1,   [Invoice no],    '' as F2,[Transaction Ref] ,   '' as F4 , [Acquisition Nominal] ,  [Acquisition Date], [Acquisition Price]  ,   '' as F8,   '' as F9 ,   '' as F10 ,   '' as F11 ,   '' as F12 ,   ''  as F13,   ''as F14  ,   '' as F15 ,   '' as F16,   '' as F17,   til '' as F50.  so if new file is coming you configure new str string for it. use a combo or something to change header string.
Please vote if its working. Please revert back incase of doubts.